# Angular 6 installation - error with some packages

Tags: angular

I am having a problem with angular 6, some packages show up as `<error>`.

```
ng -v
```

[image]

I can't create projects because of this. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to uninstall and install again angular cli:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify

# if npm version is < 5 then use `npm cache clean`
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with typescript 2.8.3 dependency. I had to do identical as below. The commands were:

```
Update manually the angular packages to 6.0.0
ng update rxjs
ng update angular/core
ng update angular/material
```

if ng update installs typescript 2.8.3 you have to install typescript version 2.7.2. angular compiler doesn't work with 2.8.3

[Check here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10621#issuecomment-386612334) for original reference.